# Static structure - definitions, objects, members

Tags: c++, static, struct, structure

1.What is the use of static structure other than linkage?

```
static struct test //THIS ONE
{
  int a;
};
```

2.What is the use of using static like this one? When i create this and try use the static member (either through the structure object) it shows "undefined reference to `test::a'"

```
struct test
{
  static int a; //THIS ONE
};
```

3. What is the use of creating a static structure object?

```
struct test{
  int a;
};

int main()
{
  static test inst; //THIS ONE
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a static structure or class in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am able to declare the structure as static. I am thinking that if i use static struct i will not be able to refer it in an external file or another translation unit. Is it not this way?

Comment: @Kaushik: Not in standard C++, you can't. [GCC rejects the first example](http://ideone.com/nETZsE).

Comment: @Kaushik, just define your structure inside cpp file, or inside header file which you will not include inside other source files. Lack of definition will prevent usage of your class in other files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It is only linkage specific - it will make your `test` structure have internal linkage (visible only in the current file). **Edit:** This is valid only for function and variable declarations - not for type definitions.

   ```
   //A.cpp
   static int localVar = 0;

   void foo(){ localVar = 1; /* Ok, it's in the same file */ }

   //B.cpp
   extern int localVar;
   void bar(){ 
   /* 
      Undefined reference - linker can't see
      localVar defined as static in other file. 
   */
      localVar = 2; 
   }
   ```
2. This is a static field. If you declare some field inside struct `static` it will be shared data member for all instances of that structure.

   ```
    struct test
    {
        static int a;
    };


    // Now, all your test::a variables will point to the same memory location.
    // Because of that, we need to define it somewhere in order to reserve that 
    // memory space!
    int test::a;

    int foo()
    {
        test t1, t2;
        t1.a = 5;
        test::a = 6;
        std::cout << t2.a << std::endl; // It will print 6.
    }
   ```
3. This is static local variable. This will not be stored on call stack, but on the global area, so all calls to the same function will share the same `inst` variable.

   ```
      void foo()
      {
           static int i = 0;
           i++;
           std::cout << i << std::endl;
      }

      int main()
      {
          foo();  // Prints 1
          foo();  // Prints 2
          foo();  // Prints 3
          return 0;
      }
   ```

Comment: Point 2: How to access it somewhere in main? It is giving me an error "undefined reference to `test::a'".

Comment: @Kaushik Added, take a look on part 2 example.